# Homomorphic image of a ring.

Tags: ring-theory

Can we say that any ring $T$ is a homomorphic image of a free algebra $R$ (over the prime ring of $T$)? I could not get the answer. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds true.  Say $P$ is the prime ring of $T$.  $T$ is an algebra over $P$, and that algebra is clearly generated by all the elements of $T$.  So if we define $R$ as the free $P$-algebra generated by $T$, there should be a natural $P$-algebra homomorphism $f: R \to T$ which is onto.  An element of $R$ is a finite formal sum of terms of the form $pt_0...t_{n - 1}$, and it's easy to define $f$ using the addition and multiplication in $T$.